# What lightsaber training did Luke Skywalker receive?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, luke-skywalker

Luke's only on-screen lightsaber training was given by Obi-Wan Kenobi during the hyperspace jump to the Alderaan system.

Did Luke receive further lightsaber training prior to the final battle on the Death Star II? If yes, how did he receive these training?

Seeking answers for Disney canon as well as the Legends EU canon.

Comment: Probably [not enough](http://overlypositive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/star-wars-luke-lightsaber-in-eye-obi-wan-kenobi.jpg).

Comment: If you specifically want *legends-only* answers, this would stop being a dupe.